# Can't connect to heroku Postgres using DataGrip

Tags: heroku-postgres, datagrip

I have a problem, after I had a **"database maintenance"**(01), I can not connect to it through DataGrip. Instead, I see other people's logins and databases linked to them(02). I checked the correctness of my username and password several times, but nothing changes. Help me please!
(P.s When I use a URL connection in my application, everything works fine.)

01

[image: 1]

02

[image: 2]

Comment: Try invoking "Force refresh" in the context menu of the database. Seems some system tables should be scanned again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what my problem was. In my carelessness.For some reason my tables were hidden automatically. I don't know how it happened, but I just went to the visibility settings and turn them on.

Sorry for taking up your time.